# Вывести изображение в цикле angular

Tags: angular

Использую `angular` и на главной странице есть изображение. Все ок. Но проблема в том что их будет 20, не ставить же мне 20 классов `landing__about-body`. Я понимаю что надо через цикл, но как взять изображения из `assets\images\landing` и оотобразить на странице, не понимаю. Как можно реализовать это?

```
<div class="landing__about">
    <div class="landing__about-title">About</div>
        <div class="landing__about-body">
            <div class="landing__about-img">
                <img class="landing__about-img" src="landing/about.png"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать контекст вебпака, он создается из определенного выражения. Вообще `require.context` это фича самого вебпака и это, можно сказать, общая форма чанкинга кода.

В компоненте где вы хотите получить все названия файлов с изображениями делаем следующее:

```
// `require.context` нету в определениях типов
declare const require: any;

function getPaths(req) {
    return req.keys().map(req);
}

const images = getPaths(require.context('../абсолютный-путь-к-папке-assets-images-landing', false, /\.(png|jpe?g)$/));

class Component {
    public images: string[] = images;
}
```

В шаблоне у вас будет доступен массив с именами файлов изображений:

```
<div class="landing__about-img" *ngFor="let image of images">
    <img class="landing__about-img" [src]="'/assets/images/landing/' + image">
</div>
```